# VIM: Why is this function hanging VIM?

Tags: debugging, function, vim

I have added the following fine function to my status bar to show which function is currently being edited in C-derived languages:

```
set statusline+=%{WhatFunctionAreWeIn()}
fun WhatFunctionAreWeIn()
    let strList = ["while", "foreach", "ifelse", "if else", "for", "if", "else", "try", "catch", "case"]
    let foundcontrol = 1
    let pos=getpos(".")          " This saves the cursor position
    let view=winsaveview()       " This saves the window view

    while (foundcontrol)

        let foundcontrol = 0

        " Go to the character before the last open {
        normal [{
        call search('\S','bW')

        " If the character is a ) then go to the character
        " preceding the () section
        let tempchar = getline(".")[col(".") - 1]
        if (match(tempchar, ")") >=0 )
            normal %
            call search('\S','bW')
        endif

        let tempstring = getline(".")

        for item in strList
            if( match(tempstring,item) >= 0 )
                let foundcontrol = 1
                break
            endif
        endfor

        if(foundcontrol == 0)
            call cursor(pos)
            call winrestview(view)
            return tempstring
        endif
    endwhile
    call cursor(pos)
    call winrestview(view)
    return tempstring
endfun
```

However, after a few minutes VIM hangs. Disabling the function prevents the hang, so I feel confident that this function is to blame. Is there anything in there that might hang VIM? Is there a better way to accomplish the task of showing the currently-edited function in the status bar?

Thanks.

Comment: Found this. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=610. I haven't used it myself but I guess it should be robust because it is based on ctags.

Comment: Thank you Gowtham, but that script does not work for PHP files. If an array is declared above the cursor position in the function, then it shows the name of the array and not of the function.

Comment: Do you observe the hang for all file types, or just PHP? Could you provide a file that triggers the hang?

Comment: Thanks, Prince. It seems that leaving the cursor outside of functions for an extended period causes the trouble. The memory use and both CPU cores spike. Closing the Konsole window doesn't help, either. I must `kill -9` the VIM process. Tested on PHP and C files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your strategy for determining whether to keep moving to surrounding braces is too aggressive:

- Suppose your cursor is on the `f` in a preprocessor directive `#endif` between two functions.
- Since you're between two functions, there is no unmatched `{` for `[{` to jump to, so the cursor doesn't move.
- Your `match()` against `strList` hits the `if` in `#endif`, causing the loop to continue.
- The loop never exits.

I suspect a ctags-based approach, like @Gowtham suggests, will work better, even if it requires some customization.

Comment: Thanks, David. I will try ctags solution again and see if I can customize if for PHP.